# Test selenium Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to run my test selenium in Jenkins. I use Maven with Testng to run my test in jenkins. I have a simple configuration to do it :

```
package Testselenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;      
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;       
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;       
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;   
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class NewTest {      
        private WebDriver driver;       
        @Test              
        public void testEasy() {    
            driver.get("http://localhost");  
            String title = driver.getTitle();                
            Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("TimDevOps"));   
        }   
        @BeforeTest
        public void beforeTest( ) {  
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
        }       
        @AfterTest
        public void afterTest() {
            driver.close();          
        }       
}
```

I would like to configure the same test what I do in Selenium IDE but when I extract my java file and I replace my configuration above it doesn't work :

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class test extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("http://localhost/", "*chrome");
    }
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
    }
}
```

Eclipse doesn't know selenium object.

Is there someone know how can I mix both of file please ? Thank you in advance

Comment: you shall better look for how to run tests using `mvn` .

Comment: I use the pom.xml where there is the configuration about Maven

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. But I'm guessing it is this you want.

```
package Testselemium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;


public class NewTest extends SeleneseTestCase {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testEasy() {
        driver.get("http://localhost");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("TimDevOps"));
    }

    @Test

    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"button\"]");

    }
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest () {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it's exactly what I want to do but eclipse underline "selenium" in public void testTest()

Comment: are both 'import com.thoughtworks.selenium.' and 
'extends SeleneseTestCase' present in your code?

Comment: Yes there is everything. Eclipse says :"The type SeleneseTestCase is deprecated". I tried to add :"@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")" but the build fail anyway